# complex mysql Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I am having a little issue here.
So I have two tables and I need to fetch data in what i think is a complex way.
So below is a summary of the two tables

**clients**

1. client_id
2. name
3. booked *[default is 0]*

**accommodation**

1. accommodation_id
2. client_id
3. date
4. price

---

1. What I would like to have is select all client id's from **tbl
   clients** where booked is 1
2. then using the **client_ids** select all rows in accommodation whose
   **client_id** is an of those returned in step 1

What i had in mind proved difficult for me

```
$select_accomodation = "SELECT * FROM `accommodation` WHERE `booked` = 1";
if($select_accomodation_run = @mysql_query($select_accomodation))
{
    //awesome code that does no 2       
}
```

What is the best possible way to accomplish tasks 1 and 2. Hopefully in one mysql statement

Comment: A single join condition does not make a query complex btw :)

Comment: Also in case nobody has mentioned these to you 1: Avoid using the `@` error suppression operator as it masks problems and is inefficient and 2: don't use the `mysql_*` functions. Use prepared statements with either `PDO` or `mysqli`. :)

Comment: thank you @jacobwalker0814. i will see to that

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to select all accommodations for booked clients you could do

```
SELECT a.*
FROM accommodation a
INNER JOIN clients c ON a.client_id = c.client_ID
WHERE c.booked = 1
```

Comment: Wow. That was much cleaner than my initial instinct, which was to use a subquery. Then again, subqueries can often be replaced by joins when used in the WHERE clause, and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you jacobwalker0814. And @McAdam331. i am not quite fluent with JOIN statements, so I prefer subqueries too

Comment: Where did you learn SQL? I just started about a month ago at an internship, I ordered the book MySQL by Joel Murach and it is easily the best reference I could have hoped for. [Here's the book on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Murachs-MySQL-Joel-Murach/dp/1890774685/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1405982017&sr=8-1&keywords=murach%27s+mysql) The same author also has a book on PHP and MySQL together I believe, if PHP is common practice for you I would look into it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 select t1.client_id, t2.accommodation_id, t2.client_id, t2.data, t2.price from clients t1 JOIN accommodation t2 on t1.client_id = t2.client_id WHERE t1.booked = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

My thought, is first write a subquery that gets the Ids you want for part 1, which is:

```
SELECT client_id FROM clients WHERE booked = 1
```

Then, you can use that subquery inside another query for the accomodations table using the IN clause

```
SELECT a.* FROM accomodation a WHERE a.client_id IN (SELECT c.client_id FROM clients c WHERE c.booked = 1);
```

Comment: What is wrong with it? Admittedly I was unable to test it, but why wouldn't it work?

Comment: Your comment, before you edited it just said 'This is not good.' You never said why, so I just don't understand what's wrong.